# WSO2 web links asks for user authentication

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I was trying to learn about WSO2 ESB and use some examples available on the web by WSO2 employees. However accessing these links ask for user authentication. Do I have to register somewhere or is there any temporary issue with the website.

I was trying to learn about WSO2 ESB entitlement mediator and for that I tried to access this URL

http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwso2.org%2Fproject%2Fesb%2Fjava%2F4.0.0%2Fdocs%2Fmediators%2Fentitlement.html&ei=Z3PBUfW6HMO3rAfZwoG4BA&usg=AFQjCNGpv2CdS_dZshfV70d4fRlCxgYk_A&bvm=bv.47883778,d.bmk&cad=rja

Help me get access to these resources.

Thanks.

Comment: Now you should be able to access the given link. http://wso2.com/project/esb/java/4.0.0/docs/mediators/entitlement.html

Comment: Great. I can access it now. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Please access WSO2 docs from the Wiki Dashboard: http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/dashboard.action

Here is a link to the ESB Docs http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Enterprise+Service+Bus+Documentation

You can find information about Entitlement Mediator from following link.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Entitlement+Mediator

I hope this helps.

Thanks!